# Употребление местоимения "это" при указании на целое предложение

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика, местоимения, местоимение

*Считается, что знания — это волшебная таблетка, которая сделает тебя успешным и богатым. Университеты делают на ЭТОМ неплохой бизнес.*

Допустимо ли использовать местоимение "это" для указания не на конкретный объект, а на всю мысль, которая выражена в предыдущем предложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что мысль (в отличие от факта) лучше обозначить:

Считается, что знания —  волшебная таблетка, которая сделает тебя успешным и богатым. **Университеты строят на этом мнении (суждении) неплохой бизнес.**

Answer (score 1):

**Допустимо ли использовать местоимение "это" для указания не на конкретный объект, а на всю мысль, которая выражена в предыдущем предложении?**

Это допустимо и широко распространено.

> Франсуаза, когда мне было всего пять лет, научила меня говорить не
>   Тарн, а Тар, не Беарн, а Беар. Благодаря **этому**, когда мне исполнилось
>   двадцать лет, я знал... (Марсель Пруст, "Пленница")

Answer (score 1):

> Считается, что знания — **это** волшебная таблетка, которая сделает тебя успешным и богатым. Университеты делают на **ЭТОМ** неплохой бизнес.

Два *это*, относящиеся к разным объектам, — стилистически плохо.

Второе *это* само по себе неудачно. Трудно сразу сообразить, к чему именно оно относится. Пoэтомy я за вариант, предложенный Jasmin: "Университеты строят на этом мнении (суждении) неплохой бизнес".